# If I disable the Job which is running it will stop the Job?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL SERVER 2008, If I disable the Job which is running it will stop the Job ?

I have tested the iteM two weeks ago, and the result is it will rollback the running job according the last reslut of Disable/Enable.

I have double tested the item, but the result is opposite. It will not stop the running job when the job has been disabled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you disable a job while it is running, it WILL continue the execution that was already started. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: no problem. please remember to vote and mark as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Hi, Diego. Are there some method to stop the execution when disable the job? So far as I know, check the job running status, and use the system sp to stop the job, But maybe there is exception when stop the job which is already completed. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean? when the job is done it is not executing anymore

Comment: When call the stop sp the job is running, but the job is completed when the stop sp begin execute.

Comment: Just confirmed, created a job with 1 step of WAITFOR DELAY '00:04:00'; started job then disabled, it continued to run for 4 minutes then exited successfully.